# Naming convention for constraints that are not explicitly defined

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

Is there a way to force SQL server or SSDT project to name constraints in a certain convention when they are not defined explicitly. To give an example, let's say I have below

```
CREATE TABLE City
(
    CityId      INT             NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name        VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    CountryId   INT             NOT NULL REFERENCES Country(CountryId)
)
```

and I want the constrains above named as though I've written it like below:

```
CREATE TABLE City
(
    CityId      INT             NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name        VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    CountryId   INT             NOT NULL
)

GO
ALTER TABLE City
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_City_CityId
PRIMARY KEY (CityId)

GO
ALTER TABLE City
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_City_CountryId_Country_CountryId
FOREIGN KEY Country (CountryId)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: That would be nice indeed but there is no such thing to my knowledge

Comment: But you can Rename all these constraints in a single go after creating them. Check this http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2709/script-to-rename-constraints-and-indexes-to-conform-to-a-sql-server-naming-convention/

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps modify the dacpac after it has been built but it isn't a simple task.

I would follow my first rule of constraints in Sql Server, "Name them".

Is there a reason why you don't want to name them?

Comment: I think the point is not a constraint without a name, but a constraint with name which makes sense to the OP, not a sql server defined name (which makes sense, they do not tend to be logical names).

Comment: Mainly to save time on the typing. I guess it will also help on following a convention and preventing typing mistakes.